# Getting highest value card in list

Tags: python

I have a list of cards:

```
    hand = ["KC", "QC", "4C", "0S"]
```

And I always want to get the highest card in terms of rank, like in this list

```
    rank_cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
```

The highest card in this case would be:

```
    "KC"
```

How can I do this for any sort of hand I get?

I was thinking of using a dictionary to rank cards in terms of index, like this:

```
    d = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(rank_cards):
        d[c] = i
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The dictionary would be the best option in terms of performance.

Comment: Is this for a school assignment? Why not attempt to do your own homework yourself, then ask Stackoverflow if you run into any specific problems.

Comment: @MGOwen Seems like a pretty specific question/problem to.  Shows the current attempt.  Asks for optimizations.  Seems like a model SO question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `max` built-in function and use a custom `key` function.

```
>>> max(hand, key=lambda c: rank_cards.index(c[0]))
'KC'
```

If you want to sort the entire hand in descending order based on rank

```
>>> hand.sort(key=lambda c: rank_cards.index(c[0]), reverse=True)
```

If you wanted slightly better performance by pre-computing indexes (basically, your solution, but one-lined in a dictionary comprehension).

```
>>> rank_cards_map = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(rank_cards)}
>>> max(hand, key=lambda c: rank_cards_map[c[0]])
```

Comment: This would be a one-liner but with a performance of O(K*n) being K the amount of cards you have in your hand and n the len(rank_cards). To build a dictionary would have a better performance as the cost would be max(O(n), O(K)) only (considering access in a hashmap is O(1))