# Highest value card in a list but matching names rather than letters

Tags: python

I've only recently started coding and I'm not sure how to properly articulate the question but it is the same as:
[Getting highest value card in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403492/getting-highest-value-card-in-list)
Except that I'm using full names rather than letters.
So far I've only got:

```
hand = ["king of diamonds","queen of spades","three of clubs","six of clubs","ace of hearts"]
card_order = ["ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king"]

print(max(hand, key=lambda c: card_order.index(c[0])))
```

However when I try running this it just gives me

```
ValueError: 'k' is not in the list.
```

I know that "\b" is meant to match full words however I wouldn't even know where to begin to place it into the code. I'm unsure what is actually wrong so an explanation alongside an answer would be greatly appreciated but isn't necessary.

Comment: `c[0]` means the first character of list item, try `c.split()[0]` for first word. `\b` refers to regular expressions which is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking for the index of the first character of each card in your hand. That's not in `card_order`, so you get an exception.

Check for the index of the card name, which is the first element of the list we get by splitting the full card name.

```
print(max(hand, key=lambda c: card_order.index(c.split()[0]))
```